# How can i include some predefined stuff in JIRA Greenhopper project

Tags: project-management, jira, jira-agile

I am using `JIRA + green Hopper` for agile project managment . My projects are usually web application based.

So for every project and i have some 4-5 predefined `EPICS` and stories which i want to inlcude in all projects like

```
ServerSetup
Analytics Setup
Backups
```

Is there any way that i can set them as some template so that dont need to enter them again and again

Answer (score 0):

This link may be helpful for you https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/32564/is-it-possible-to-generally-setup-project-templates.

In 2 words JIRA doesn't provide such functionality and there are some plugins which may help you to handle this. If you are running your projects on OnDemand version then you may consider the option of writing simple program or script which will be creating a predefined list of tickets for any project you specify. You can take a look at examples of using REST API. The link below contains few examples of how to create issue via REST API. https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/JIRA+REST+API+Example+-+Create+Issue#JIRARESTAPIExample-CreateIssue-Exampleofcreatinganissueusingprojectidsandissuetypeids.